# I want to apply a limit for discount amount on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer, rwd

I want to apply a limit for discount amount on checkout. I am providing multiple discount to my customer what I want whenever customer checkout the maximum discount limit will be 50% of the order amount on checkout.

Comment: are you using the coupon code or you have custom code to apply the discount?

Comment: I am using both, what I want if the discount amount exceed the limit of above condition,then checkout can not be processed.

Comment: you can limit in price Ex. $60 or $70 but you can't do in 50% for that you need to do customization.